# Facebook Graph API - Pictures posted to Fan page by app are not showing to all users

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am writing a Facebook App for my organization.  We want to automate posting pictures to certain albums on our Fan page using the graph api.  I have created the Facebook app in Facebook.  My app requests publish_actions and manage_pages permissions in order to post the photos to the albums.  I have written all the code to make it post the pictures.  I have successfully posted pictures to albums on our Fan page using the app.  I have **NOT** submitted my app to Facebook for "Review" to be approved.

**Problem:**
Only my user can see the photos in the albums that were posted by the app.  I have editor permissions on the Fan page.  I am the only developer of the app. If I add a tester or another developer to the app, that new user can see the photos that have been posted to the fan page by the app.  So, my guess is that Facebook has to review and approve my app before the photos that are posted by the app can be viewed by all users.  But I have found no documentation to prove my theory.  Am I right or have I done something else wrong?  I don't want to go through a 7 day wait for the review and approval and still have the same problem. Please let me know.

Comment: No Facebook doesn't need to approve it. You just need to take the app Live. There is a big Live button under Review & Status

Comment: Post that as the answer and I will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Facebook doesn't need to approve it. You just need to take the app Live. There is a big Live button under Review & Status